# Delayed Job with i18n on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have this task with delayed_job:

```
def any_method
 UserMailer.delay(queue: "Email", priority: 3).to_user_when_his_account_is_suspended(user, locale)
end
```

If I send a email as rails mode:

```
def any_method
 locale = params[:locale]
 UserMailer.to_user_when_his_account_is_suspended(order, locale).deliver
 #more code
end
```

The email is sent on the proper locale/language.

However **delayed_job** does not recognize the proper locale/language. On this case I get locale with `locale = params[:locale]`, you can see the next example:

```
locale = params[:locale]
UserMailer.delay(queue: "Email", priority: 3).to_user_when_his_account_is_suspended(user, locale)
```

Mailer Code:

```
 def to_user_when_his_account_is_suspended(user, locale)
  @user = user
  @locale = locale
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => t('.user_account_has_been_suspended'))
 end
```

**How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: What do you mean 'delayed_job does not recognize the proper location'?  Do you want to add 'deliver'?

Comment: If you add `.deliver` method to delayed_job method, you will catch a error. I mean that the sent emails, are not sent on his proper language. The language, is received on my method with params[:locale]. Thank you!

Comment: params[:locale]? That doesn't sound right. Do you mean that you reference the local variable locale inside the task, because that's the only way it would work.

Comment: Thank you @JoePym. Can you paste a response of how it works your fix for this question?. Thank you!

Comment: I mean, you say "recieved on the method with params[:locale]". For example of good code: "I18n.locale = locale". For bad "I18n.locale = params[:locale]". Does that make sense? I imagine it probably is correct, but I thought I'd check. Can you post a sample of where you are setting the locale in the mailer?

Comment: Thank you, I have added the mailer method. I received locale from `params[:locale]`. Also, I have tried with only `locale` but is does not working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first, why I think your 'existing' mailer code is working when it's not in DJ.

Your locale is set through I18n.locale. This is set on a thread specific level...hence, assuming you are setting I18n.locale somewhere for the user, then Rails is using that to send.

However, DJ will use a separate process entirely...so it can't inherit the locale! This means it will fall back to whatever your default locale is.

How I'd change your mailer:

```
def to_user_when_his_account_is_suspended(user, locale)
  @user = user
  old_locale = I18n.locale
  I18n.locale = locale
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => t('.user_account_has_been_suspended'))
  I18n.locale = old_locale
end
```

This will temporarily change the language for the thread in the mailer, and then, like a good citizen, it will set it back to the old value at the end of the request.

Obviously, if you are doing this all over the place, you want to extract it into a helper method that yields control.

Comment: Thank you Joe is correct your response. Now is working fine :D. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is a better approach, hope it helps somebody:

```
 def to_user_when_his_account_is_suspended(user, locale)
   @user = user
   I18n.with_locale(locale) do
     mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => t('.user_account_has_been_suspended'))
   end
 end
```